# Can a drow monk cast spells with charisma?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monk, drow

I'm new to D&D and my character is a drow monk.

Am I still allowed to use the spells that come with my race (i.e. darkness, dancing lights and faerie fire)? Or does the fact that I'm a monk cancel out these abilities and render me incapable of casting them? In the sense that do I use my charisma as my race dictates or my ki as my class does?

Comment: I have a feeling there's more to this question than what you've stated (based on drow lore and some house-rules on drow I've read), what makes you think you lose the spells you gain with your race selection?

Comment: @daze413 I can't speak for Ethir but in one of the games I've played DM's and players alike have house ruled along this line of thinking; monk's don't cast spells, even those they have inborn, as part of their disciple.

Comment: @daze413 it's just when i described my character to my friend (who has experience playing) he told me that since i'm a monk i cannot cast spells, (even though in the research that i've done i couldn't find any of that information). also what he told me sounded kinda sketchy so i decided to double check.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Yes**

The racial bonuses you get do not interfere with your class. That includes spells. In fact, the racial spells you gain would be considered separate from spells you learn as a result of your class in that they would use the specifies modifier (in this case charisma) as opposed to the classes spell casting modifier.

For example, a drow wizard would cast his wizard spells with his intelligence modifier but would cast his drow racial spells with his charisma modifier.

When writing down your spells on your character sheet you should note which spells are from class and which are from race so you remember to use the correct modifier.

Answer (score 5):

You will still have the spells according to your race, and cast them at the levels specified, using Charisma if that is what is stated.  These are separate from the Monk abilities.  Nothing says otherwise, anywhere.